# Sort list generated via backend with JS or JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question was asked many times before because I've check most of posts on this topic.
I'm using [this](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/01/view-mode-switch/) view mode switcher to get my data in tile and list format. It's great, but because of using list I can't easily get the sorting part out.

I've tried this code bellow but this orders data high to low to high and it's kinda useless because i need something like select with 3 options

- low to high
- high to low
- random/default

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.listWrapper li')).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute('data-position').localeCompare(b.getAttribute('data-position'));
  }).forEach(function(currValue) {
    currValue.parentNode.appendChild(currValue);
  });
});
```

So then i tried

```js
var divList = $(".qaz");

function sortPriceHighLow(){
  divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(b).data("price")-$(a).data("price")});    
  $("#isotope-grid").html(divList);}

function sortPriceLowHigh(){
  divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(a).data("price")-$(b).data("price")});    
  $("#isotope-grid").html(divList);}
```

This completly changes the layout of the switcher and dosn't work

this is my html **NOTE** class names and ids are diffrent here than in js files due to my trying diffrent approches through the day **so don't comment it doesn't work because names are different**

```html
<ul class="listWrapper">
{% for x in productsInfo  %}
    <li data-position="{{x.priceNormal|floatformat:'-3'}}">
        <div class="qaz">
            <a class="cbp-vm-image" href="{% url 'detail' id=x.id %}"><img src="{{ x.pic1.url }}></a>
            <h3 class="cbp-vm-title">{{ x.title  }}</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
% endfor  %}
</ul>
```

So if someone has something with select that sorts data via price I woudl be astonished.
Have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data-position` attribute from `li` tag and then sort the result and add them to `listWrapper` again using `.html()` .Then , for generating random you can get the `length` of li and append `lis` using `before($(".listWrapper li:eq(" + j + ")"))` where `j` is random position .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var divList = $(".listWrapper li");

function sortPriceHighLow() {
  //get attr position from li
  var result = divList.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(b).data("position") - $(a).data("position")
  });
  $(".listWrapper").html(result); //add result inside ul 
}

function sortPriceLowHigh() {
  var result = divList.sort(function(a, b) {
    //use attr position
    return $(a).data("position") - $(b).data("position")
  });
  $(".listWrapper").html(result); //add result inside ul 
}

function random() {
  var length = $('.listWrapper li').length //get length of li
  $('.listWrapper li').each(function() {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * length); //just get random no
    $(this).before($(".listWrapper li:eq(" + j + ")")); //append them
  })


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="sortPriceHighLow()">High to Low</button>
<button onclick="sortPriceLowHigh()">Low to High</button>
<button onclick="random()">Random</button>
<ul class="listWrapper">

  <li data-position="12">
    <div class="qaz">
      <a class="cbp-vm-image" href=""><img src="{{ x.pic1.url }}"></a>
      <h3 class="cbp-vm-title">12</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-position="13">
    <div class="qaz">
      <a class="cbp-vm-image" href=""><img src="{{ x.pic1.url }}"></a>
      <h3 class="cbp-vm-title">13</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-position="14">
    <div class="qaz">
      <a class="cbp-vm-image" href=""><img src="{{ x.pic1.url }}"></a>
      <h3 class="cbp-vm-title">14</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-position="15">
    <div class="qaz">
      <a class="cbp-vm-image" href=""><img src="{{ x.pic1.url }}"></a>
      <h3 class="cbp-vm-title">15</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```